# vue-cli npm install issue

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

I get the following error in npm when I run `npm install -g @vue/cli`

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4
>   (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4:
>   wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm ERR! file cmd npm ERR! path cmd npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
>   errno ENOENT npm ERR! syscall spawn cmd npm ERR! protobufjs@6.8.8
>   postinstall: `node scripts/postinstall` npm ERR! spawn cmd ENOENT npm
>   ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the protobufjs@6.8.8 postinstall script. npm
>   ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Danijel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-09-24T12_48_07_8Z-debug.log

Can anyone help me solve this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've tweaked the format of your question to make it easier for people to read the question and understand the problem you are facing. Feel free to add any extra information you think is important to the question.

Comment: You should look in `2018-09-24T12_48_07_8Z-debug.log` as instructed.

Comment: The problem seems to be with node's ***child_process.spawn***
which is used by the **protobufjs@6.8.8 postinstall** script

See this:
`child_process.spawn` does not work with `npm run scripts` on windows
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3675

Answer (score 1):

`fsevents` Looking at the error this dependency is looking to work on `darwin` which is Mac and you are using Windows. It's a library allows applications to register for notifications of changes to a given directory tree in MacOS. Your `vue` app should be fine without it on windows.

`protobufjs` is a Protocol Buffers Library. It's used for serializing structured data. Take a look at https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf for protocol buffers for windows. It's a binary to support protocol buffers from github.

Comment: Note: the `fsevents` one is just a warning that it's skipping that optional dependency. The `protobufjs` is what's actually *breaking*, and the details are likely in the log file mentioned in the message.